# What is the risk of guard relay and exit relay being one and the same?

Tags: exit-relays, guard, protocol

Looking at the circuits build for a client during a Tor process, I have noticed the following:
Four circuits were built.

On the first circuit the guard node was **a1**.

On the second circuit the exit node was **a1**.

On the third circuit the guard node was **a1**.

On the fourth circuit the guard node was **a1**.

What are the risk of simultaneously having circuits that use same node for guard relay and exit relay?
P.S. This is not a hypothetical question. I have documented the actual circuits built by Tor process for reference.

Comment: I would assume it's the same probability as any other unused onion-router being selected.
It's probably not possible to have a router as both the guard and exit on the same circuit, however.

Comment: These are related questions: 1.https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3756/why-adding-guard-exit-ee-node-in-tor-yeild-more-catch-probability-than-adding 2.https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4685/what-is-the-risk-of-guard-exit-node-in-tor-compare-to-guard-and-exit-node-separa

Answer (score 4):

The [Tor spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/tor-spec.txt#l1022) says:

> ### 5.3. Creating circuits
>
> When creating a circuit through the network, the circuit creator
>      (OP) performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Choose an onion router as an exit node (R_N), such that the onion
>           router's exit policy includes at least one pending stream that
>           needs a circuit (if there are any).
> 2. Choose a chain of (N-1) onion routers
>           (R_1...R_N-1) to constitute the path, such that no router
>           appears in the path twice.

(2) seems to rule out the exit node and the guard node being the same, although strictly speaking the phrasing is somewhat ambiguous.